# Old animated sci-fi movie about a family traveling on a starship

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

When I was little, my dad rented an animated sci-fi movie, or perhaps a series. I guess it was around 1990-95. But I cannot say how old the movie was when I saw it.

From what I remember about the story, it was about a family traveling on a starship. Parents and a child. I think they shipwrecked. The parents left the child in care of the ship's systems and robots. They either died or went looking for help, don't remember exactly. The main story then focuses on the child who is being brought up by the robots.

If I remember correctly, the name of the movie was translated to "Bludny Holandan" in Czech, which means "Flying Dutchman" in English. However, I failed to find any mention of such a movie under this name.

I don't remember the animation style. If I had to guess, it would be Japanese, similar to Ulysse 31.

---

It is not:

- The *Lost in Space* live action movie from the late 90's. Apart from the obvious differences (animated/live action), the movie I am talking about had much more serious tone.
- The Russian show *The Mystery of the Third Planet*.
- The French animated movie *Les Maîtres du temps*.
- The Japanese animated movie called *Flying Phantom Ship*.

Comment: I remember watching this film in about 87/87 when I was 11. I've also been trying to find it. I remember there wasn't much talking, a cave with tentacles and a strange but friendly creature......if you find it let me know.

Comment: Hm, the tentacle cave rings a bell.

Comment: I took the liberty of improving the title to make it less generic. If you disagree, feel free to the edit it again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the plot seems a lot like the plot I asked about in a previous question of mine, I am copying and pasting [the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/207483/58193) to my question.

> [image: Poster for Ultima Misiune showing the name as Fiul Stelelor]
>
> - The original name is *Ultima Misiune* (even if in the linked image it seems to be called *Fiul Stelelor* as well). The English translation of the title "Ultima Misiune" is *Last Assignment* or *Last Mission*
> - It was a Romanian cartoon of 1989 (it should be by the same team that made another animated movie, that seem a bit more famous, which is [*Delta Space Mission*](https://www.animest.ro/delta-space-mission-.aspx))
>
> There is a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pg/UltimaMisiune/about/) about it, but if you look for "ultima misiune" on YouTube it is possible to find some clips as well.

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure but it could be the Russian show [*The Mystery of the Third Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mystery_of_the_Third_Planet)

Comment: Looks interesting, but this is not it. Thanks for your suggestion anyway though.

Answer (score 3):

Might be the French animated movie [*Les Maîtres du temps*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps) (1982) as it also involves a boy shipwrecked on a planet and a serious tone and also cave with tentacles and strange friendly creature

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer, but this is not it either.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is the Japanese animated movie called [*Flying Phantom Ship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Phantom_Ship).

Your description of the story vaguely matches it but the name surely is really close.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not it.

Comment: From what I remember Earth wasn't featured in the movie and it took place on an alien, uncolonized planet.