# 80s cartoon about a boy stranded on a planet

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a strange science-fiction cartoon movie I watched as a kid (80s).

It's about a boy in a starship who, after losing his parents in an accident in space, lands on an planet, where he's raised by the native aliens. When he grows up, he finds his starship and is helped by the board computer to remember his parents, after which he leaves the planet.

At some point after leaving the planet I think he also meets somebody in a kind of medieval armor.

It should be European (I think French or from East Europe), but it's neither *Fantastic Planet* (*La Planète sauvage*) nor *The Masters of Time* (*Les maîtres du temps*).

Some other info I can remember:

- I've seen it in Italy, on local TV broadcasters
- The protagonist had an animal, which was a scarf-like white creature
- Before leaving the planet, the protagonist found that the aliens who raised him were dying (I don't remember if they disappeared or became of stone)

Comment: Hi there! :) there's already some good info in there, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in your post? For instance, what language did you watch it in? If you saw that in French, do you remember if it was featured in "special airing times" such as _Récré A2_? Things like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been through a good chunk of the Europeans ones in [these year llists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animated_feature_films_of_1979) (1979 to 1990) but did not find 'the one' - I may have missed it, of course! I left out the American and Asian ones though. Just putting that here :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, I could find something about this animated movie.

[image: Poster for Ultima Misiune showing the name as Fiul Stelelor]

- The original name is *Ultima Misiune* (even if in the linked image it seems to be called *Fiul Stelelor* as well). The English translation of the title "Ultima Misiune" is *Last Assignment* or *Last Mission*
- It was a Romanian cartoon of 1989 (it should be by the same team that made another animated movie, that seem a bit more famous, which is [*Delta Space Mission*](https://www.animest.ro/delta-space-mission-.aspx))

There is a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pg/UltimaMisiune/about/) about it, but if you look for "ultima misiune" on YouTube it is possible to find some clips as well.